# n以下の素数の個数を高速に求めるには？

Tags: ruby, python, アルゴリズム

pi(n)をn以下の素数の個数と定義します。
pi(n)の正確な値を高速に求めるにはどのようなアルゴリズムを用いればよいでしょうか。

2×√n 程度のデータを用いて計算するコードを記しておきます。

(Ruby 2.2)

```
def pi(n)
  m = Math.sqrt(n).to_i
  keys = (1..m).map{|i| n / i}
  keys += (1..keys[-1] - 1).to_a.reverse
  h = {}
  # 1を除いた個数
  keys.each{|i| h[i] = i - 1}
  # 「素数」もしくは「i以下の素数では割り切れない合成数」の個数
  (2..m).each{|i|
    if h[i] > h[i - 1] # このときiは素数
      hp = h[i - 1]
      i2 = i * i
      keys.each{|j|
        break if j < i2
        h[j] -= h[j / i] - hp # iで初めて割り切れる合成数(ちなみにi2以上）を除く
      }
    end
  }
  h[n]
end

p pi(10 ** 8)
```

(Python 2.7)

```
import math

def pi(n):
    m = int(math.sqrt(n))
    keys = [n // i for i in range(1, m + 1)]
    keys += range(keys[-1] - 1, 0, -1)
    h = {i : i - 1 for i in keys}
    for i in range(2, m + 1):
        if h[i] > h[i - 1]:
            hp = h[i - 1]
            i2 = i * i
            for j in keys:
                if j < i2: break
                h[j] -= h[j // i] - hp

    return h[n]

print pi(10 ** 8)
```

（参考）
(Ruby 2.2)
上記コードと、Rosetta Code で紹介されている Wheel factorization を用いた方法
（http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#With_a_wheel）とで比較してみた。

```
require 'benchmark'
puts Benchmark::CAPTION
puts Benchmark.measure{
  p pi(10 ** 8)
}
puts Benchmark.measure{
  p eratosthenes2(10 ** 8).size
}
```

おおよそ以下のような結果になります。

```
      user     system      total        real
5761455
  0.218000   0.000000   0.218000 (  0.210384)
5761455
  8.362000   0.312000   8.674000 (  8.699177)
```

速さで比較すると、
上記コード＞ Wheel factorization を用いた方法（＞エラトステネスの篩）
となっている。

Comment: 近似値でよいからとにかく高速にしたいということであれば、素数定理を使う方法もあります。

Comment: （途中経過）1〜√n までの k に対しては、h[k]を正確に求める必要があるが、それ以上の√n  個の部分については、h[n] 以外はそれほどきっちりしなくても良さそうだ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathWorld の以下のページに method, time complexity, storage complexity が載っているので、実装したときの速さの目安になるかと思われます。
（http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html）

余談ですが、上記ページには Π(10^25) (Büthe (2014)) までしか載っていませんが、OEISのA006880には Π(10^26) まで載っています。
（https://oeis.org/A006880/list）

なお、次のように改良してみました。

```
def pi(n)
  m = Math.sqrt(n).to_i
  keys = (1..m).map{|i| n / i}
  keys += (1..keys[-1] - 1).to_a.reverse
  h = {}
  keys.each{|i| h[i] = i - 1}
  (2..m).each{|i|
    if h[i] > h[i - 1] # このときiは素数
      hp = h[i - 1]
      i2 = i * i
      h[n] -= h[n / i] - hp
      # h[n / j]は「i = jのときのh[n]に呼び出されるまでは計算しておく」ことにし、
      # i = jのとき、h[n / (j + 1)]から計算していくことにする
      keys[i..-1].each{|j|
        break if j < i2
        h[j] -= h[j / i] - hp
      }
    end
  }
  h[n]
end
```

n = 10^12 を計算させた結果

```
      user     system      total        real
37607912018
264.796000   0.078000 264.874000 (268.561594)
```

元々のコードで計算させた結果

```
      user     system      total        real
37607912018
304.062000   0.078000 304.140000 (308.404353)
```

Answer (score 1):

時間が書いてないので早いのか遅いのか分かりませんが・・・
Cでエラトステネスの篩を使った場合１．６秒程度でカウントできます。
~ ./a.out 100000000
Time:1.625000

*** prime count: 5761455 ***
~
[エラトステネスの篩](http://www.crimsoneyes.jp/src/soe.c)
ちなみに計算量はO(n log log n)です。

Comment: はやいなぁ・・・うちの機械じゃこんなもんですね＾＾；　　  
  
    ~/test \time -h ruby tst1.rb
5761455
        1.24s real              1.15s user              0.09s sys
    ~/test